# Please undelete this answer that was converted to a comment

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answer

In the question [How do I stop Windows 10 from updating my graphics driver?](https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver) The correct answer is pretty much "Run this tool from Microsoft" however [Random](https://superuser.com/users/307/random) deleted [that answer](https://superuser.com/a/964492/25625) and converted it to a comment.

It really is the "Correct" answer to the problem and NorPhi should get credit for it but because the answer was "deleted" by a moderator it can not be voted to be undeleted by high rep users.

Comment: I agree with Scott.  Especially since comments are supposed to be temporary and may disappear.  It should remain as an answer,  NorPhi could have been asked to flesh it out.  Deleting it does a dis-service to the other users looking for the answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta - I offered the user a chance to earn a bounty.  I still feel a link only answer was correctly deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am on the fence on that.  Sometimes it is the only answer and the reviewers and moderators should not be too rigid.  My opinion is that he should have been requested to flesh it out.  That would have helped him for his future answers and helped other users who are looking for the answer.  As it stands, it does a dis-service to other users.  My rep is not high here, but it is high enough on Stack Exchange for reviewing answers.  And I have to struggle with this constantly.  Thanks for the Bounty.

Comment: @RohitGupta - He was given a chance.  The answer was flagged as being low quality, a reviewer likely indicated link-only answers are not considered to be enough here, the moderator decided those flags were warranted.  I just maintain, the answer should have been higher quality to begin with, support articles are often moved without redirection.  A full description of what to do would have taken 5 minutes to write up by the author of that answer, my perspective, by submitting what they did they sort of indicated zero desire to improve it.  Of course I have high quality expectations for SU answs

Comment: @Ramhound, Thanks, I was obviously not privy to that. :-)

Answer (score 7):

What is the "this tool" that they should run?

From the visible on-site content there is no mention of even the name of the tool, the app, or even any steps or where to look on their system to follow with the troubleshooting guide.

For those who cannot yet see it, the entire answer is:

> That happend a lot, so MS provides a trouble shooting guide:

If an answer cannot make any sense when you remove the links, it is not a valid answer.

It is a non-answer and should be deleted, or at least fleshed out that when the link is gone or the page moved you have something close to an idea of what was really there.